# sqlite3 file import

Tags: import, sqlite

is here a way to import a file into table with ":" being the separator?

for example I have file test.txt with

```
value1:result1
value2:result2
```

want to use something like this on the CLI:

```
sqlite> .import test.txt table
```

and at the end I would have:

```
+--------------+
|value1|result1|
+------+-------+
|value2|result2|
+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 6):

use `.separator :`

```
.separator STRING      Change separator used by output mode and .import
```

[Here](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you use `.help`, you might notice something interesting :

```
sqlite> .help
...
.help                  Show this message
.import FILE TABLE     Import data from FILE into TABLE
...
.separator STRING      Change separator used by output mode and .import
...
```

So, `.import` might be what you are searching for ;-)