# Import PG Dump Into Sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, sqlite

So I have a PG dump and am wanting to import it into my sqlite3 db. What are some ways that I can go about this? I'm guessing that it might need to be converted to another format?

Answer (score 1):

rake db:structure:dump
and use tool like sqliteman (available for linux) to import sql file into your sqlite db.
Hope that helps
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) file import utility.  Just convert it to a tab separated text file.

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628974/sqlite3-file-import) that should show you how to use it.